# Unity Camera Change C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have three characters and each of them has a camera attached to them.By default they are disabled but one.I made a character selector which is supposed to change them.I have a problem where I can move the selected one but the camera stays at the last one.
Here is the script:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityStandardAssets.Utility;


    public class GameManageer : MonoBehaviour {



        public Camera[] cams = new Camera[3];
        public Character CurrentCharacter;
        public List<Character> Characters = new List<Character>();
        public List<Item> AllItems;
        bool ShowCharWheel;
        public int SelectedCharacter;
        public int lastCharacter;
        public static GameManageer Instance;



        void Awake(){
            Instance = this;

            foreach (Character c in Characters){
                c.Instance = Instantiate(c.PlayerPrefab, c.HomeSpawn.position, c.HomeSpawn.rotation) as GameObject;
                c.Instance.GetComponent<PlayerController>().LocalCharacter = c;
            }
            ChangeCharacter(Characters[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedChar")]);
        }


        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {


        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {


            if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.C)) {
                ShowCharWheel = true;
            } else {
                ShowCharWheel = false;
            }



        }


        void ChangeCharacter(Character c){

            lastCharacter = SelectedCharacter;
            SelectedCharacter = Characters.IndexOf (c);

            cams [SelectedCharacter].gameObject.SetActive (true);
            cams [lastCharacter].gameObject.SetActive (false);
            CurrentCharacter = c;
            Characters [lastCharacter].Instance.GetComponent<PlayerController> ().CanPlay = false;
            Characters [SelectedCharacter].Instance.GetComponent<PlayerController> ().CanPlay = true;              
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("SelectedChar", SelectedCharacter);
        }



        void OnGUI(){
            if (ShowCharWheel) {


                GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(Screen.width - 64, Screen.height - 192,64,192));
                foreach (Character c in Characters){
                    if (GUILayout.Button(c.Icon,GUILayout.Width(64),GUILayout.Height(64))){

                        ChangeCharacter(c);
                    }

                }
                GUILayout.EndArea();
            }

        }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Character {

        public string Name;
        public Texture2D Icon;
        public GameObject PlayerPrefab;
        public GameObject Instance;
        public Transform HomeSpawn;
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Item{
        public string Name;
        public Texture2D Icon;
        public ItemInstance InstancePrefab;
    }
```

Comment: Camera.main =   cams [SelectedCharacter]; ---

may not work but it can lead you to somewhere..

Comment: Camera.main is read-only

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
cams[SelectedCharacter].enabled = true;
cams[lastCharacter].enabled = false;
```

Comment: there is no such method for cameras

Comment: Can you check
cams[SelectedCharacter].camera.active = true;

Comment: It is itself a camera and if i want to set it I must use .gameObject.SetActive(true); but for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: Where do you fill the cams array?

Comment: cams[lastCharacter].enabled = false;
cams[SelectedCharacter].enabled = true;

Comment: And all Cameras have to be tagged as "MainCamera"

Comment: I don't really know why it doesn't work but  atleast I know it doesn't even disable or enable

Comment: Do you drag the prefabs into the array?

Comment: no I instantiate them i only drag the prefab cameras

Comment: You have to drag the camera instances into the cams array. Then the cams[].enabled = true should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Depth:

```
foreach (Camera cam in cams)
{
    cam.depth = cam == cams[SelectedCharacter] ? 10 : 0;
}
```

I think the real problem here though, is that you have more cameras in the scene which you have to manage as well, other then *only* the last and current selected character... in which case:

```
foreach (Camera cam in cams)
{
    cam.SetActive(cam == cams[SelectedCharacter]);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say it but it does nothing

Comment: are you setting ALL cameras your not using to depth 0?

Comment: I did exact as you said

Comment: I'm not sure where i have to put it

Comment: instead of the two lines `cams [SelectedCharacter].gameObject.SetActive (true);`
            `cams [lastCharacter].gameObject.SetActive (false);`

Comment: Yes it does work for prefabs but not for instantiated gameObjects :/

Comment: what do you mean exactly?